# fetch data from more than one rss feed with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rss, rss-reader

I'm new to Nextjs, and I've been tinkering with a newsfeed tool to become familiar with the framework. I want to fetch data from  list of RSS feeds. I've been tinkering around with it, and it's not functioning the way I thought it should. How would i go about doing it?

Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Articles() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Frss%2Fcnn_topstories.rss&api_key=kiu9hxfe1661vn0cmz3jpj8dueorj0idmiucugqr');
                const data = await res.json();
                const items = data.items.slice(0, 20);
                setItems(items);
            } catch {
                setError(true);
            }
        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    if (error) {
        return (
            <section>
                <div>
                    <h3>Latest Articles</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <p>Failed to fetch data, please try again later.</p>
                    </ul>
                    <a
                        href={"https://www.cnn.com/"}
                        target={"_blank"}
                        rel={"noopener noreferrer"}
                    >
                        Read on CNN
                    </a>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }

    return (
        <section>
            <div>
                <h3>Latest Articles</h3>
                <ul>
                    {items.map((item, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <a href={item.link} target={"_blank"}>
                                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </ul>
                <a
                    href={"https://www.cnn.com/"}
                    target={"_blank"}
                    rel={"noopener noreferrer"}
                >
                    Read More on CNN
                </a>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

Comment: what is the output. Specify the error or out put using some snap shot. So people can help u.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error. It works just fine, but I want to fetch data from more than one RSS feed, and i'm having difficulties getting it to work. It returns no data and gives no error messages.

Comment: will the url be changed for more than ne RSS ??

Comment: @judia do you mean if items is empty it should be returned an error?

Comment: One of my problems, yes. Here is the Github: https://github.com/jvkrakowski/news-feed
I know there is a better way to write that code.

Comment: Ah! it's very difficult to look in GitHub... you can check it out for the solution to this problem 

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-itemlength-fy72q9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Your application is having 2 return which is wrong and hard approach. The easy way is to do condition rendering .The code below does it.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Articles() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false); // null or false both can work in your case

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Frss%2Fcnn_topstories.rss&api_key=kiu9hxfe1661vn0cmz3jpj8dueorj0idmiucugqr');
                const data = await res.json();
                const items = data.items.slice(0, 20);
                setItems(items);
            } catch {
                setError(true);
            }
        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    if (error) {
        return (
          
        );
    }

    return (
       {error ? 
          <section>
                <div>
                    <h3>Latest Articles</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <p>Failed to fetch data, please try again later.</p>
                    </ul>
                    <a
                        href={"https://www.cnn.com/"}
                        target={"_blank"}
                        rel={"noopener noreferrer"}
                    >
                        Read on CNN
                    </a>
                </div>
            </section>
             :
        <section>
            <div>
                <h3>Latest Articles</h3>
                <ul>
                  {/* use condition for items so if items is undefined for some reason the code does not crash */}
                    {items && items.map((item, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <a href={item.link} target={"_blank"}>
                                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </ul>
                <a
                    href={"https://www.cnn.com/"}
                    target={"_blank"}
                    rel={"noopener noreferrer"}
                >
                    Read More on CNN
                </a>
            </div>
        </section>
}
    );
}
```